# Equivalent of the word "quadrant"

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, computing

What would be the equivalent of the word quadrant when referring to 1/2 and 1/8 of an area?
I'm looking for a more specific term than simply a half.

To give more detail, I'm looking for a term which can refer to a node of a binary tree data structure. In a quad tree data structure, you can refer to each node as a quadrant. I'm looking for the equivalent reference in a binary tree. It would be incorrect to refer to a node in a quad tree as a quarter or a quarter-plane, likewise for a binary tree it would be incorrect to refer to a node as a half or half-plane.

Comment: One half is perfectly technical, and I am not sure to what end I'd be looking for an obscure term where a universally understood one will do.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm actually looking for a term which specifically means a sub-node of a binary tree, in terms of area. For example, in a quad-tree you refer to each sub-node as a quadrant. It wouldn't be correct to refer to a node as a quarter or a quarter-plane, likewise in a binary tree it would be incorrect to refer to each sub-node as a half or a half-plane.

Comment: Well. *That* makes sense. Though of course you'll agree we can't quite read people's minds to that extent. So providing such information up-front is always a good idea.

Comment: It’s not specific to binary, quaternary, or octonary relations, but in a tree structure in general, I would normally call any individual node a ***branch***. In a binary tree, the singular ‘branch’ will itself be equal to ‘half’, but somehow sounds more specific.

Comment: Nodes in binary trees are often called the "left" and "right" nodes of their parent.

Answer (score 2):

1/2 = semi-circle or half

1/8 = octant

In general, they are all orthants.

Comment: Is there a more technical term for 1/2 than simply one half?

Comment: @Someone not that I could find or know of.

Comment: *"The upper half-plane"* is a technical term used in mathematics; if there were a better word, I suspect mathematicians would be using it.

Answer (score 2):

*Octant* for an eighth.

For a half, there's the general *half*, and some more specific terms; of a circle, *semi-circle*, of an n-dimensional space, *half-space*, of a 2-dimensional space, *half-plane*. Of a line, *ray*.

Answer (score 0):

For "half", depending on the context, you might also use "[bifurcate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bifurcate?q=bifurcate)". The disadvantage for the "use case" is that this generally describes the splitting into two, rather than the resultant (two) areas.